# Woocommerce -> Analytics -> Orders add customer billing phone to report and excel export

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to add customer billing phone number to Woocommerce -> Analytics -> Orders report. Currently it has only customer name. Does anybody knows how to add this?

[image]